# Regular expression: match an incomplete search string

Tags: regex

Is there a regular expression for matching a string that is not necessarily complete?

Example:

> 1. some other **supercalifragilisticexpialidocious** random things
> 2. and maybe **supercalifragilistic** meaningless padding
> 3. lorem **superca** ipsum dolor

I would like to match whichever left part of **supercalifragilisticexpialidocious** there is each time. There are not necessarily spaces around words.

The expected result would be to find:

> 1. **supercalifragilisticexpialidocious**
> 2. **supercalifragilistic**
> 3. **superca**

This is similar to matching the same character any number of times, but more universal.

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean. I hope now after some reformatting it is more clear that it is about matching a particular piece of text that is not necessarily complete.

Comment: What are the expected results for the examples?

Comment: The expected result of 1, 2 and 3 is each time to find the **bold** section, i.e. 1: supercalifragilisticexpialidocious, 2: supercalifragilistic, 3: superca.

Comment: How can one tell the word boundaries when there are no spaces?

Comment: The idea is like this: if *superc...* is found anywhere in the text regex begins matching and keeps going until a letter is found that does not occur on that place in *supercalifragilisticexpialidocious*: then it stops. Example blah*supercal*foo would stop at foo because f is not the right next letter.

Comment: What language/runtime is this (since regex flavors vary)? What is the expected result if the text contains two matches? Do you want the longest match, or the first match, or all matches? In the latter two cases, why doesn't the 's' in 'some' match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this isn't a regex, but I think your objective can be accomplished better using code. Here's an example of a JavaScript function that matches as much of an input string as it can:

```
function matchMost(find, string){   
    for(var i = 0 ; i < find.length ; i++){
        for(var j = find.length ; j > i ; j--){ 
            if(string.indexOf(find.substring(i, j)) !== -1){
                return find.substring(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

For example, if you call `matchMost("supercalifragilisticexpialidocious", "lorem superca ipsum dolor")`, it  will return the string "superca". If `string` doesn't contain a single character from `find`, the function will return false.

Here's a JS Fiddle where you can test this code: http://jsfiddle.net/n252eyw1/

---

**UPDATE**

This function matches as much of the left side of an input string as it can:

```
function matchMostLeft(find, string){   
    for(var j = find.length ; j > 0 ; j--){ 
        if(string.indexOf(find.substring(0, j)) !== -1){
            return find.substring(0, j);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sjy312ae/

Comment: Hi Paul, Nathan thanks for this. I almost thought I will end up with such a piece of code, but given that regex is about automatically constructing a finite automaton for walking along a string I hoped there must be an expression for this. It seems so much made for a regex solution.

Comment: @user1357415: This solution needs some serious bugfixing; `matchMost("super", "hyper")` returns "per"

Comment: That's not a bug, that's by design.

Comment: I see your point; you are trying to match _any_ substring of supercalifragilisticexpialidocious. But OP specifically asked for the _left_ part of supercalifragilisticexpialidocious. I think you should remove one of the `for` loops.

Comment: Indeed. I added that solution above.

Answer (score 2):

There is, but it's not tidy at all (and probably not very performant either). This regex matches at least 3 characters on the left side and up to `supercal` as written; the way to extend it should be fairly plain.

```
(?:sup(?:e(?:r(?:c(?:a(?:l)?)?)?)?)?)?
```

Paul's answer is likely far more useful in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an alternative solution. It is similar to Paul's in that it uses `indexOf` rather than regular expressions. This also makes it equally case-sensitive. My approach should perform better in exceptional cases where Paul's solution would cause excessive calls to `indexOf`; typically when:

- the needle is very long (worse than *supercalifragilisticexpialidocious*), and
- you have a lot of separate texts to scan, and
- the majority of texts either do not match, or contain only short matches.

If this is not the case with you, then please use Paul's solution, as it is clean, simple and readable.

```
function getLongestMatchingPrefix(needle, haystack) {
    var len = 0;
    var i = 0;
    while (len < needle.length && (i = haystack.substring(i).indexOf(needle.substring(0, len + 1))) >= 0) {
        while (++len < needle.length && haystack.substring(i, i + len + 1) == needle.substring(0, len + 1)) {}
    }
    return needle.substring(0, len);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ov26msj5/